Find an equality similar to the problem in the IMC 2002
First, I will recall the IMC 2002 problem:
Problem 3.Let ( n ) be a positive integer and let
$$
a_k = \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}, \quad b_k = 2^{k-n}, \quad \text { for } \quad k = 1, 2, \ldots, n
$$
Show that
$$
\frac{a_1 - b_1}{1} + \frac{a_2 - b_2}{2} + \cdots + \frac{a_n - b_n}{n} = 0.
$$
I tried changing the number 2 to 3. Specifically, I considered the sequence $\{u_n\}$ defined by
$u_1 = 2, \quad u_n = \frac{n}{3^n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{3^k}{k}, \quad \forall n \geq 2 $.
After exploring this, I obtained the following two results:

$ u_{n+1} = \frac{n+1}{3n} \left(1 + u_n\right), \quad \forall n \geq 2 $.
The ordinary generating function for the sequence $ \left\{ \frac{u_n}{n} \right\}$ is

$$ A = \dfrac{X}{3 - X} \cdot \ln \dfrac{1}{1 - X}. $$
I think that using the generating function above, it may be possible to find a beautiful identity similar to the one in the IMC 2002 problem, perhaps by replacing 2 and 3 with some other number ( p ). However, I haven't found anything yet. I would appreciate any suggestions or ideas.
